# Could not locate compojure in classpath

Tags: clojure, installation, compojure

I am trying the various Getting started examples and I can get a basic hello world example working with basic HTML in the route as such

```
(ns hello-world
  (:use compojure.core ring.adapter.jetty)
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes example
  (GET "/" [] "<h1>Hello World Wide Web!</h1>"))

(run-jetty example {:port 8080})
```

But when I attempt to use the html helpers like so

```
(ns hello-world
  (:use compojure ring.adapter.jetty)
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes example
  (GET "/" []
    (html [:h1 "Hello World"])))

(run-jetty example {:port 8080})
```

Then I get the following error

[null] Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate compojure__init.class or compojure.clj on classpath:  (core.clj:1)

Comment: May be you mention (:use compojure.core ring.adapter.jetty) instead (:use compojure ring.adapter.jetty)?

Comment: There are many examples still out in the intraweb that include (:use compojure). This appears to be pre Compojure 0.4 examples as described below. The problem above still stands for people still following these examples.

Comment: I think your second example is missing "[]". It should be (GET "/" [] ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv mentions in a comment, you use `(:use compojure ...)` in the second example. You should switch to `(:use compojure.core ...)` and then maybe pull in some additional dependencies for the other functionality that you use (like [`hiccup`](http://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) (<- this is a link to the GitHub repo), which is now a separate project, for the HTML-building DSL).

My guess is that you're trying to follow some tutorials written for Compojure 0.3 while using Compojure 0.4. The latter does not include the `compojure` namespace at all and has been slimmed down a lot, with the basic HTTP handling delegated to [`ring`](http://github.com/mmcgrana/ring) and various other pieces of functionality spun off to separate projects (like the aforementioned `hiccup`).

Fortunately there are good resources on the 0.3 -> 0.4 transition, e.g. [this blog entry](http://formpluslogic.blogspot.com/2010/04/migrating-from-compojure-032-to-040-and_01.html) by Brenton Ashworth. If you can't find something that's been removed from Compojure proper, chances are you'll be able to learn where to find it now from that. See also [this follow-up discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/compojure/browse_thread/thread/4da66a70254671a3/ae5b4157e51ba1c9?#ae5b4157e51ba1c9) on Compojure's Google group for errata and additional details.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this was exactly it. i needed to include hiccup.core to get the (html [:h1 "foo"]) stuff working.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with a Compojure "Hello World" and had this problem (as well as many others that are getting muddled in my brain). Another complication is a lot of the Compojure documentation on the web is already out of date. Bottom line, these are the step you want to follow:

1. Have an up-to-date version of [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). Make sure you follow the installation instructions on the github site. (Do *not* go through macports; their Leiningen is out of date.)
2. Follow Compojure instructions [here](http://weavejester.github.com/compojure/docs/getting-started.html).

*Note* that the file name is incorrect. It should be src/hello_www/core.clj NOT src/hello-www/core.clj.

Comment: Thanks Julian, this was the example I could get working. However it is the exmaples that contained the (html [:h1 "foo"]) that I could not.  It does appear that the hiccup.core is now required as of Compojure version 0.4.0.